# How to blacklist amdgpu driver?

Tags: drivers, kernel, amdgpu, blacklist

I have found that `amdgpu` driver is disturbing in suspend. I want to uninstall or blacklist it.

How to blacklist `amdgpu`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

```
blacklist amdgpu
```

As initramfs contains modprobe configuration, update the initramfs and reboot:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Check whether the driver blacklisted or not, the following command should output nothing.

```
$ lsmod | grep amdgpu
```