# How to uninstall AMDGPU?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I have a fresh install of `18.04` on my desktop with Radeon Vega 64 GPU. Since I installed AMD GPU official driver, I have a collection of problems.

For a week, the mouse was lagging after a few hours. Now, the entire screen freezes after a few hours. There is no graphic output. If I turn off the monitor and start it again, there is no signal. However, the machine still works as a webserver.

I uninstalled `AMD GPU` with the command,

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

but then, Ubuntu does not boot into the graphical interface (freezes before the purple screen).

I tried to blacklist the driver, according to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080217/how-to-blacklist-amdgpu-driver).

Again, Ubuntu does not come up.

It is frustraiting, as my machine is practically useless because of this stupid driver. I am thinking of buying an Nvidia GPU.

Do you know a safe method to get rid of `AMD GPU` driver? Because I don't remember any of these problems with the fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. I believe the native firmware worked much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar happened to me trying to figure out settings and drivers for Mythtv on 18.04 with Kaveri. If 'sudo amdgpu-pro-uninstall' didn't return errors, and the dpkg --purge didn't work (I also did both). Then my many driver install/uninstall resulted in missing files for the radeon driver fixed for me with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

And if that fails, then maybe uncomment Enable=true under debug in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf. Then use Virtual Terminals (I ssh in from my laptop) to switch between multi-user and graphical.target so you can review ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.conf for more clues. Similar debugging and searching on askubuntu led me to the reinstall above.

Answer (score 4):

I got also the same problem, and those commands helped me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt install xserver-xorg
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Answer (score 2):

The amdgpu-pro-install is a script file that you can read. To uninstall, apparently you can type in:
`./amdgpu-pro-install --uninstall`

This worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> into root recovery upon boot, you can do

`$dpkg -l | grep -i amdgpu`

and `dpkg --purge` what you find there for amdgpu.

Then you can try the AMDGPU-open drive, instead of the propriatary,the AMDVLK open source driver, or even Mesa 18.X + Linux 4.19.

You have a beast of a card, which has been successfully ran under 18.04, and still have several options before giving up on it.

Comment: should be grep amdgpu-pro not amdgpu (which is the built-in free driver)

Comment: @NickBailuc `dpkg -l | grep -i amdgpu` will list all files with amdgpu* patten, including `amdgpu-pro` . Also suggesting that we should only be looking at `amdgpu-pro` files is not appropriate as we have no knowledge what `amdgpu-pro-uninstall` did. We need to first remove the corresponding drivers, and then reinstall them to avoid future issues.

Comment: @NetIceGear thank you! Thank You! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who wants to reinstall the amdgpu drivers (uninstall first completely) from kisak mesa due to not loading or freezes i recommended this (which fixed it for me:)

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-all amdgpu* libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-radeon1 && sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 && sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf
```

The reinstall part is for anyone who uses the kisak mesa drivers which can be added:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

For the radeon driver you use this reinstall command (which is the one used by preinstalled systems):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-core libdrm-radeon1 && sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf
```

For optimizing or card specific parameters use this wiki on arch:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AMDGPU

It is recommend to blacklist NOUVEAU and AMDGPU or RADEON driver, the decision depends on which you want to use