# Properly setting up AMD card on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, graphics, mesa, amdgpu-pro

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu on PC and, as a longtime Windows user, I installed  amdgpu-pro graphics from AMD's official site. However I'm experiencing problems with amdgpu-dkms crashing and realized there are mesa drivers that are, in opinion of most, better than amdgpu-pro.

So I want to install latest stable Mesa drivers on my PC and I read Ubuntu 20.04 comes with Mesa preinstalled but when i run

```
glxinfo | grep Mesa
```

I get no output. Does this mean that, since I installed amdgpu-pro, Mesa is blacklisted? I checked blacklisted modules but I didn't find Mesa among them.

Anyways, in browsing how should I go about replacing amdgpu-pro with mesa, I came across these 2 questions:

1. [How to uninstall AMDGPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117883/how-to-uninstall-amdgpu)
2. [How to blacklist amdgpu driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080217/how-to-blacklist-amdgpu-driver)

I want to do this safely, so should I firstly install mesa, then blacklist amdgpu and then, if it all works run:

```
sudo amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

If not, what are the steps of replacing amdgpu-pro with mesa and what is the safe way of deleting amdgpu-pro?

Comment: "I get no output." -- Does it mean that your external display don't detect by Ubuntu?

Comment: It means that, when I type "glxinfo | grep Mesa" in Terminal, Terminal doesn't output anything, just goes to next line as if Mesa doesn't exist. If i try "glxinfo | grep OpenGL" I get expected output